# Regex, remove specific format

Tags: regex

I have a text like below:

Yth Bpk xxxx xxxxxx, Terima kasih menjadi cust xxx dg No kontrak 01234567890 angs Rp.xxx.000. Batas akhir pembayaran tiap 1 bulan tgl 10, masa kredit 12 bln.

I want to capture "12 bln" and I have my regex below:

```
(\d{0,1}\d[\s]*(?:bulan|bln|hari|hr|Januari|Februari|Pebruari|Maret|April|Mei|Juni|Juli|Agustus|September|Oktober|Oktobr|November|Desember|January|February|Pebruary|March|April|May|June|July|Augustus|September|October|November|December|JAN|FEB|PEB|MAR|APR|MAY|JUN|JUL|AUG|SEP|OCT|NOV|DEC|Jan|Feb|Peb|Mar|Apr|May|Jun|Jul|Aug|Sep|Oct|Nov|Dec|Jan|Feb|Mar|Apr|Mei|Jun|Jul|Agu|Ags|Sep|Okt|Nov|Des?<!tiap)[\s]*[\d]*)
```

This regex also capture some texts that I am interested to. But using this regex it will catch "1 bulan" and "12 bln". How can I remove "1 bulan" from the catch value?

Comment: Your regex matches `1 bulan`, if you do not need to match it, remove `bulan|` from the list of alternatives.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
(\d{0,1}(?<!tiap\s)\d\s*(?:bulan|bln|hari|hr|Januari|Februari|Pebruari|Maret|April|Mei|Juni|Juli|Agustus|September|Oktober|Oktobr|November|Desember|January|February|Pebruary|March|April|May|June|July|Augustus|September|October|November|December|JAN|FEB|PEB|MAR|APR|MAY|JUN|JUL|AUG|SEP|OCT|NOV|DEC|Jan|Feb|Peb|Mar|Apr|May|Jun|Jul|Aug|Sep|Oct|Nov|Dec|Jan|Feb|Mar|Apr|Mei|Jun|Jul|Agu|Ags|Sep|Okt|Nov|Des)[\s]*[\d]*)
```